# Java I am unable to find more than 1 regex match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to scrape this web page. I need to find all names under "Rank name"

Website: https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall?table=0&page=1

But I am having a major issue. Only the first match is found (Lynx Titan). `log(m.group(1).split("\"")[0]);` matches with Lynx Titan. But if I replace [0] to 1 or 2, it does not work. It should display the next name. Any help is appreciated

```
public void getRsn() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall?table=0&page=1");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0");
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String s =  serverResponse.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("user1=(.*)\">").matcher(s);
        while(m.find()) {
            log(m.group(1).split("\"")[0]);
        }

        serverResponse.close();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use regex - use JSoup

Comment: P.S. Your code works fine for me BTW, the split part seems unnecessary - the 1-st group does not include quote character

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
URL url = new URL("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall?table=0&page=1");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0");
conn.connect();
BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String s =  serverResponse.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
serverResponse.close();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(user1=)([a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\�]+)(\">)").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println((m.group(2).replaceAll("\\�", " ")));
}
```

My output was,

```
Lynx Titan
Hey Jase
ShawnBay
senZe
Tomdabom
Karma
Harmony
DedWilson
GodTormentor
Vinny
borsi
Brundeen
Aziz
Eeli
baile y
gaslighter73
Dan Gleesac
blind idiot
he box jonge
Gustav
Randalicious
Oskar
Killzone
moksi
Capt King
```

#### Update

The Charsets is actually `ISO_8859_1`  not `UTF_8`. So you can make this answer better.

```
URL url = new URL("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/overall?table=0&page=1");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0");
conn.connect();
BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

String s =  serverResponse.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
serverResponse.close();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(user1=)([a-zA-Z0-9\\ \\ ]+)(\">)").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println((m.group(2)));
}
```

*Note: There are two different space characters are there in the document*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your regex: you're only matching one user. Also, each iteration of the `while` loop will find anotherr user, not each element of the split (which you actually don't need).

Use a regex that matches every user, and *only* the user's name:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=user1=)[^\"]+").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // the entire match is the user name
}
```